# How to redirect to another site automatically in Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am trying to make my progressive web app automatically redirect to another site when the user clicks on the icon on their desktop.

As of right now when the user clicks on the icon it opens up a landing page where the user can link on the link to be redirected.

I'm using Next.js and JavaScript. I appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: i mean you can do it with a single html file, why would you use nextjs just to redirect?

Comment: anyway you can just add `window.location.href = 'your url'` inside a useEffect on the first page that loads after opening 'the file'